# How to draw a horizontal line using prawn/rails on X axis at a specific point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

A user can specify a margin-bottom for a page and I want to be able to draw a horizontal line showing where they have placed it. I have defined margin_bottom in my PDF document (A4 size).

All I need to do is add the specified margin to the X axis and draw a line. However, how can I draw this line?

From my knowledge, I could call something like this

```
stroke_horizontal_line(0, 0 + margin_bottom)
```

However, this isn't working and I need it to be the full width of the page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think `stroke_horizontal_line` works a bit different than you think (if I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly)

`stroke_horizontal_line(x1, x2, at: y)` Draws a horizontal line from `x1` to `x2` at the vertical height of `y`, where y starts at 0 at the bottom of your document (after bottom margin, not at the bottom of the page).

So, I think you are trying to draw a horizontal line across the whole page, at a specific height which is defined by some variable `margin_bottom`, to accomplish that with `stroke_horizontal_line` you can do this:

```
# You can set a stroke color, if you set it to white it is possible that you just
# forgot to set it back to black.
stroke_color 0, 0, 0, 100

# You can also set the line width
line_width 2

# This would draw a horizontal line across the whole page (not over your side margins)
# at the height of margin_bottom + your document bottom margin (measured from the bottom up)
stroke_horizontal_line(0, bounds.width, at: margin_bottom)
```

You can also use `stroke_horizontal_rule`, which just draws a horizontal line at you current cursor position, so you would have to place the cursor on the right spot before using that method.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

stroke_horizontal_line (y), (y), at: (x)

Answer (score 0):

```
stroke_horizontal_rule
```

Should do it.